# How can I generate documentation for C# that outputs as Markdown for an Azure DevOps Wiki?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, markdown, documentation, docfx

I've been using DocFX to generate code documentation for C# and for the most part found a lot of success with it. The articles are flexible and I really like that I can use markdown to maintain them while having them live side by side with the API references. I have also already spent the time documenting walkthroughs in Markdown and building a CI pipeline.

The problem I am trying to solve is that I need to figure out a way to get my code documentation (xml comments) output to be markdown instead of html so that it can be hosted by markdown wiki solution, specifically Azure DevOps (aka TFS). Azure DevOps Wiki seems to be very similar to gh-pages from GitHub as well, so I'm interested in similar solutions that I might be able to get to work in Azure DevOps. **DocFX doesn't solve this problem because the output is .html instead of markdown**.

All of Microsoft's documentation is focused on writing documentation by hand. I'm interested in generating documentation based on the xml comments in the code.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT The accepted answer is the most relevant tool I have been able to find. What I ended up doing was using VSXMD and then a powershell script to combine all of the markdown files into 1 folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like its a long open request on [DocFx](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues/684).

This alternative solution was recommended in a couple of places that I saw [XmlDocMarkdown](https://github.com/ejball/XmlDocMarkdown).

> A console app that generates Markdown from .NET XML documentation comments.

Or you could always go with [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). Either using the stock conversion, or roll your own custom LUA filter for the conversion process.

Comment: Quick hint: XmlDocMarkdown  doesn't support the inheritdoc tag